# How do I make the container of this resume I created using html and css response in a way that if I make the browser smaller, it will follow?

Tags: html, css

So, I created this resume using HTML and CSS and I wanted to it responsive in a way that if I change the browser size, the contents including the container will adjust. I'm new to this so I'm not sure.

[This is how it looks when I change the size of my browser. As you can see, the contents and container become messy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6N4g0.png)

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Catamaran:wght@400;500;600;700;800;900&display=swap');
    

body
{
    background: #f0966b;
    font-family: 'Catamaran', sans-serif;
    margin: 30px 250px;
    


}

.name
{
    font-size: 35px;
    font-weight: 800;
}

.container 
{
    
    display: grid;
    padding: 30px;
    grid-column-gap: 1em;
    grid-row-gap: 1em;
    background-color: #f8f8f8;
    max-width: 100%;
    min-height: 100px;
    
}

.header
{min-height: 100px;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 70% 30%;



}



.subheader
{
    font-size: 19px;
    font-weight: 700;
}
    


.left-right
{
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 50% 50%;
    margin-top: 25px;
}

.footer
{
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
    margin-top: 1px;
    grid-column-gap: 2em;

}

span
{
    font-weight: 600;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Sample</title>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

     <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./sample.css">

     <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Catamaran:wght@400;500;600;700;800;900&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>

    <div class="container">
        <div class="header">

            <p class="name">
                Hello. <br> 
                I'm <span style="color: #e9692c; ">
                    Name Surname.
                </span>
            </p>

            <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/1200x/ec/de/63/ecde631ccc34c9b8086dbf7956f88eae.jpg" width="200" height="auto">
        </div>

        
            <div>
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
                tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
                quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
                consequat. 
            </div>
        

        <div class="left-right">

            <div>

            <div class="subheader">
                Skills 
                <div>━</div>
            </div>
            <div>
                 ● Graphic Design<br>
                 ● Web Design<br>
                 ● Web Development<br>
                 ● Adobe Illustrator<br>
                 ● Adobe Photoshop<br></div>
            
            </div>

            <div>

            <div class="subheader">
            <div class="exp">   
                Experience
                <div>━</div>
            </div></div>
            <div>
                <strong>2xxx-PRESENT</strong> <br>
                <span style="color: #e9692c;">POSITION</span><br>
                <span>COMPANY INC.</span>
                <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
                tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</div>
            </div>
            

            </div>

            <div><br>

            <div class="subheader">
                Education
                <div>━</div>
            </div>

            <div>2xxx-2xxx | M.A <br>
                <span style="color: #e9692c;">FRONT-END <br></span>
            University</div><br>

            <div>2xxx-2xxx | B.S <br>
                <span style="color: #e9692c;">INFORMATION TECHNOLOGY <br></span>
            University</div>


        </div>


        <div>

            <div class="subheader"><br>
                Works
                <div>━</div>
            </div>

            <div>
                <a href = "">Sprite Animation using HTML & CSS</a><br>
                <a href="">Blog Site</a>
            </div>
            
        </div>

        <div><br>

            <div class="subheader">
                Hobbies & Interests 
                <div>━</div>
            </div>
            <div>
                Web Design <br>
                Digital Illustration <br>
                Animation <br>
                Video Editing <br>
                Programming <br>
            </div>

        </div>


        </div>

        <div><hr></div>
        <div class="footer">

            <div>email</div>
            <div>contact no.</div>
            <div>linkedin</div>
        </div>




    

</body>
</html>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why do you have that large margin (250px) on the body? It's not leaving a narrow device much room for the rest. What do you want it to look like on a narrow viewport. Perhaps investigate setting the whole thing as a grid and where sensible remove use of px and replace with something related to the size of the viewport. And you may need a media query if your design changes below a certain viewport width.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is body margin size. Make that margin as %

```
body{margin: 30px 250px;}

body{margin: 30px 2%;} //Use This
```